# How to generate a virtual table to generate a sequence of dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime-generation

I'd like to generate a list of dates with the hopes of joining with another table, but I don't know what syntax to use, something similar to this:

```
SELECT dates.date, transactions.account_id, transactions.amount
  FROM (...) as dates
       LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.date = dates.date
 WHERE dates.date >= '2010-01-01' AND dates.date <= '2010-12-31'
 ORDER BY dates.date;
```

I want the dates so I don't have to further massage the data client-side. I'm using this to display a table similar to this:

```
Account    2010-01-01    2010-01-02    2010-01-03    Balance
============================================================
Chase 123        +100           -20           -70        +10
Chase 231                       +13            -9         +4
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### List of Dates

Use the [generate_series function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-srf.html) to get a list of numbers that you can add to a date in order to get a list of dates:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + s.a AS dates 
  FROM generate_series(0,14,7) as s(a);
```

Result:

```
dates
------------
2004-02-05
2004-02-12
2004-02-19
```

### Pivoting

The latter part of your question deals with pivoting the result set -- converting row data into columnar data.  PIVOT and UNPIVOT are ANSI, but I don't see them as [supported by PostgreSQL currently](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).  The most consistently supported means of pivoting a query is to use aggregate functions:

```
   SELECT t.account,
          SUM(CASE WHEN t.date = '2010-01-01' THEN t.amount END) AS '2010-01-01',
          SUM(CASE WHEN t.date = '2010-01-02' THEN t.amount END) AS '2010-01-02',
          SUM(CASE WHEN t.date = '2010-01-03' THEN t.amount END) AS '2010-01-03',
          SUM(t.amount) AS Balance
     FROM (SELECT CURRENT_DATE + s.a AS dates 
             FROM generate_series(0,14,7) as s(a)) x
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS y ON y.date = x.date
 GROUP BY t.account
```

### Dynamic Columns

...means [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/ecpg-dynamic.html).

Comment: What abou using the crosstab function to pivot? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Comment: @StarShip3000: Yes, but it's not ANSI

Comment: From the best I can find PIVOT and UNPIVOT aren't part of ANSI as of sql-2003. Can you point me to a place that says otherwise? I used http://savage.net.au/SQL/ as a place to look.